# Does the upper or lower triangle of a matrix include the main diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When one refers to the Upper or Lower Triangle of a square matrix, are the terms on the main diagonal included in one, both, or neither of the two matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main diagonal of a matrix is on both the upper triangle and the lower triangle, as others have written.

Be aware, though, that in some algorithms such as [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_Decomposition#Algorithms) the matrix is subdivided into an upper and a lower triangle, and diagonal is treated as belonging to just one or the other. The diagonal of the other matrix is then treated as known and not stored in the matrix. For example, in the Doolittle algorithm for LU decomposition the diagonal is assumed to belong to the upper triangle. The diagonal for the lower triangle is then assumed to be all $1$'s. The Crout algorithm does the opposite: the stored diagonal belongs to the lower triangle and the upper triangle's diagonal is all $1$'s.

Comment: Those decomposition algorithms are exactly what caused my confusion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are included in both.

Answer (score 0):

Usually both of them, though you should be sure this is the specific convention in whatever book/paper you're reading.